# Как сравнить два множества (set) в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, сравнение, множества

Как можно сравнить два множества ([`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) в JavaScript?

```
let a = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
let b = new Set([1, 3, 2]);
let equal = ???
```

(два множества являются [равными](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), если они состоят из одних и тех же элементов)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128855/comparing-ecma6-sets-for-equality

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант воспользоваться методом `Array.from`

```
const a = new Set([5, 1, 2, 3]);
const b = new Set([1, 3, 2, 5]);

let equal = isEqual(a, b);

function isEqual(a, b) {
  const a1 = setToArray(a),
        a2 = setToArray(b);

  return a1.length==a2.length && a1.every(function(v,i) { return v === a2[i]});
}

function setToArray(setInstance) {
  return Array.from(setInstance).sort((a ,b) => b - a);
}
```

ссылка на codepen прилагается - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXBqXP?editors=0011
а вообще, на англоязычном stackoverflow есть подобная статья https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Лучше не преобразовывать в массивы. Для малых объёмов данных не критично, но для больших это лишние операции. Вот более простой вариант, и более правильный:

```js
const a = new Set([5, 1, 2, 3]);
const b = new Set([1, 3, 4, 5]);

const isEqual = (a, b) => {
  if (a.size !== b.size) {
    return false;
  }
  a.forEach((item) => {
    if (!b.has(item)) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return true;
}

let equal = isEqual(a, b);

console.log(equal);
```

Операция по поиску элемента в Set происходит быстрее чем в массиве:
https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/447578/

Comment: Твой код не работает, убедиться в этом можно запустив сниппет. Обрати внимание, что в `a` и `b` - набор разных элементов